# How to send the full traceback code to a channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

````
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
    await ctx.send("Hey! You lack permission to use this command.")
    t=traceback.format_exc()
    await logs.send(f"```py\n{t}```")
raise error
````

That's my code to send the full traceback to a specific channel.

But it always sends

```
NoneType: None
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you mean the error type and the error or the full traceback?

Comment: the error full traceback

Answer (score 0):

For checking the permissions, You can use the CheckFailure. Also, The error variable contains the snippet error details. You can send that instead of a custom message.

````
if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
    await ctx.send(str(error))
    t=traceback.format_exc()
    await logs.send(f"```py\n{t}```")
````